# How to skip records with if else statement

Tags: cobol

Can anyone provide me logic for this problem

Only process the gtV with  bVH01-iMS-FLG = 'Y' .

1)  If not iMS-ORDER,  bypass the record , read next record  & find next gTV to check. One gTV can have multiple records in the input file gTVFLE.

2)  If iMS-ORDER,  continue process  -> abc00-PROCESS-RECORDS.Need to make sure if  any tVL didn't pass the validation/error, then the whole gTV should be held; and then continue to find/read next  gTV.

Comment: The information provided is insufficient. No one can answer this question correctly without some deatils - Where does IMS-Order come from? What are gTV and tVL?

Comment: You're going to have to expand your question. Remember that all is clear to you, but only what you describe can possible be clear to us. Show some sample input, and how you expect that to be processed. Your question should be something we can answer, not expecting us to just do your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information you have provided it appears there will be a field on some record that you are reading called BVH01-IMS-FLG, you will need to identify the condition for that using an 88 level, like so:

```
01 BVH01-IMS-FLAG pic X.
  88 PROCESS-THIS-RECORD value 'Y'.
```

It also seems that you have related records in the gTV file and those need to be processed as a group, so something like this:

```
Perform Read-gTV-Record
Perform until End-Of-File
   If PROCESS-THIS-RECORD
      Perform abc00-Process-Records
   End-IF
   Perform Read-gTV-Record
End-Perform
```

Really, you need to provide more description of what you are trying to do.  Record layouts of the gTV and what it means to be a valid tVL would be helpful.